# Using String functions on flattened chararray data

Tags: string, function, apache-pig, uppercase, flatten

**Objective : Using String functions on flattened chararray data**

**Input : test.txt**

```
file_id     file_name       created_time            accesssed_by
   1          a1                1                       user1
   1          a2                2                       user1
   2          b1                3                       user1
   3          c1                4                       user1
```

**Pig Script :**

```
  A = LOAD 'usertest.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (file_id:long, file_name:chararray, created_time:long,accessed_by:chararray);
  B = GROUP A BY file_id;
  C = FOREACH B {
   sorted = ORDER A BY created_time DESC;
   user = A.accessed_by;
   uniq_user = DISTINCT user;
   last = LIMIT sorted 1;
   GENERATE UPPER(FLATTEN(last.file_name)) AS file_name, COUNT(uniq_user) AS access_count;
};
```

Trying to use any of the string manipulation functions on top of flattened chararray data type is resulting in the below ERROR.

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 185, column 22>  mismatched input 'FLATTEN' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
```

Without using the string manipulation function on top of FLATTEN will result in the required data.

```
(a2,1)
(b1,1)
(c1,1)
```

Objective is to use some string manipulation functions to convert the file_name to the required format before persisting without going for another iteration of the data.

Going for one more iteration as below we are able to achieve our objective, can we avoid this and do the same earlier.

```
 D = FOREACH C GENERATE UPPER(file_name) AS file_name, access_count;
```

**Output :**

```
 (A2,1)
 (B1,1)
 (C1,1)
```

**Update :**

Based on @Balduz inputs converted bag to String using BagToString eval function and was able to achieve our objective.

```
   C = FOREACH B {
       sorted = ORDER A BY created_time DESC;
       user = A.accessed_by;
       uniq_user = DISTINCT user;
       last = LIMIT sorted 1;
       GENERATE UPPER(BagToString(last.file_name)) AS file_name,    COUNT(uniq_user) AS access_count;
       };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UPPER` function takes a String, but since `file_name` contains a bag, when you flatten it you are passing a list of Strings to the function, hence the error. If you really want to avoid that extra foreach, you will need to write a custom UDF that does exactly the same as the `UPPER` but taking a bag as input. Then, you would need to do the same you are doing but calling `UPPER` first and flattening after that:

```
GENERATE FLATTEN(MyUpperForBags(last.file_name));
```

Comment: Thanks @Balduz, based on your inputs : converted bag to String using BagToString eval function and was able to achieve our objective.